# How do I select a select set of numbers in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

Had to walk away from this one for the weekend.  Would love to know my nemesis is giving me the answer plus some extra stuff? i want it to display 0 - 10

```
for (let i=-1; i++< 100; i*5) {
    if (i < 0) {
        continue;
    } else if ( i > 50) {
        break;
    } else {
        console.log(i/5);
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the problem?

Comment: Looks kile `javascript`. Is it `Javascript`?

Comment: By the way, I suggest you to keep a consistent identation when making blocks of code (like shown in the suggested edition). It makes code easier to read and understand quickly.

Comment: I tested your code and **it does print from 0 to 10**, but in intervals of 0.2 each time. Does it work otherwise for you? Or else, is there some other issue with it? (perhaps, you want to round the numbers as `integers`? Please explain your issue.

Comment: @SebasSBM it’s probably JavaScript :p

Comment: Im sorry forgot to say its javascript. Its only supposed to display whole numbers 0-10

Comment: Thank you for the quick response I didn't even look because they warned me it could get swallowed up. My instincts were to use math.floor I couldn't figure out where to put it because they said I couldn't change the else if section of the code only the  for (let i=; i;i) portion. I hope this is clearer this is my first week with this and my first attempt for using stack for help. @SebasSBM yes my blocking is a work in progress. I will check again. The system rejected my first attempt so I moved things around and it let it pass so I thought that was what it was looking for. Thanks so much!!

Comment: ok I ran the code and its not quite what I wanted. So I'm going to have to put down the I will figure it myself attitude and share my logic. Its hard to explain because I only had like two 8hr days on learning how to use loops and if statements together.

Comment: here goes....I thought of using Math.floor() to clean up the answer but it only works in the console.log. from what I see I figured the logic was saying I had to start with -1 because my first number must be zero on the first run or it would not loop.  and the next numbers had to be evenly divisible by 5 to get clean numbers. And the only way to make it stop at 10 was to set the end of the loop at 100 and I had to keep in mind that if statement would stop at 51. Dang I just had to shake my head on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Languages like Python will drop the remainder when using the `/` operator.

JavaScript won't, but you can get the same result with `Math.floor()`.

```js
for (let i = -1; i++ < 100; i * 5) {
  if (i < 0) {
    continue;
  } else if (i > 50) {
    break;
  } else {
    console.log(Math.floor(i / 5));
  }
}
```